# After open my app from service can not setText to EditText

Tags: java, android

In my MainActivity XML file, I have an EditText which id is editsearch. I have a service class for listening to the clipboard text and open my app. Everything is happening fine but I can't set the text to my editsearch when my app opens from service class.

`findViewById` method is not work in the `onStartCommand` method of my service. I have also tried defining my editsearch EditText as a static property in my MainActivity class but not getting my expected result.

Here is my service class

```
package com.learn24bd.ad;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;



public class MyServiceReceiver extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("MySerivce","Service Started");
        final ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                String copiedText = clipboard.getText().toString();
                Log.i("Copied",copiedText);

                /* here i want to setText to my editsearch
                   also tried with static property
                   MainActivity.editsearch.setText(copiedText);
                 */

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: A service cannot deal with UI components, such as Views and EditTexts

Comment: thanks for your feedback. What is the way to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to consider if you really need a service to implement this or if it should be in the activity where the edittext is present. It is very likely that the latter would be the case.

Comment: Yes, need service in the background to detect the copy text from anywhere and open my app. In my main activity, I have a list view filter implemented depending on editsearch EditText. Actually, the goal is when user copy text from anywhere then my app will open, setText to my editsearch EditText and filter out the result in the list view.

Comment: You need to pass the text to the activity. See my answer.

Comment: By the way, `static` should never be used for any views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services aren't suitable for dealing with UI.

Instead, in your case, you should pass the clipboard content for the `MainActivity` class to handle. For that, pass it as an intent extra:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("clipboard_text", copiedText)
startActivity(i);
```

And receive and handle the text in your activity:

```
String clipboardText = getIntent().getStringExtra("clipboard_text");
```

Then you can set the text to your `EditText`:

```
editText.setText(clipboardText)
```